# Rewrite rule in Apache/htaccess doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This is what is in my htaccess file which is located in the same directory as my php project:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
```

I have got one link on my page that sends the user to this address:

```
http://localhost/PHPTest/index.php?article=27
```

This is the output that I want== `index.php/article_27` ?

**UPDATE:**

When I press the link, this is the output in the url:

```
http://localhost/PHPTest/index.php?article=27
```

This should be intercepted in the .htaccess in my php project folder and swap it to this:

```
 http://localhost/PHPTest/index.php/article_id_27
```

Here is my rewrite rule. But it doesnt work:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?article=([0-9]+)$ index.php/article_id_$1
```

More information. There is my project path, where index php is:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPTest
```

Comment: Aren't the arguments to `RewriteRule` in the reverse order? And what do you mean by `the server doesn't produce this`?

Comment: it doesnt work//////////

Comment: I can't say your comment sheds any more light on the problem you're facing. Be more clear on what you want to achieve and what's happening at the moment.

Comment: The url doesnt display itself as index.php/article_27.. as explained in the answer

Comment: Now you provide two different rules. The first one changes article_id_27 to article=27, and the one in the update does it the other way round. Which are you using?

Comment: Your new rule will **not** work -- query string cannot be matched with RewriteRule. For query string use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PATTERN_HERE` and then refer to it using `%1` instead of `$1` (check mod_rewrite docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html ).

Comment: hmmm..damit..I saw somewhere in a blog that you can do it that way. I will try to do it your way..

Answer (score 0):

> The url doesnt display itself as index.php/article_27

Why would it? You're pointing the link to `...article=27` and your rule rewrites **from** `...article_27` **to** `...article=27`.

In the scenario you have given, you probably want a **redirect** from `...article=27` to `...article_27`, not a rewrite.

Comment: I want to use this pattern: RewriteRule ^oldfile\.html newfile.html
// thats basically what I want ... see update